# getting data from another file + csv + html

Tags: html, csv

Apologies in advance if my question is silly as I am only learning.

I am working on this example [google pie chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart).

It is basic pie chart with its values in the in script tags of the HTML.

What I am looking for is a basic example of how this could be recreated but pulling the data from a CSV file? Or other source.

Any other advise on this process would be appreciated. Like am I better taking the data in another format?

tks

Comment: You could have an AJAX call which fetches the labels and percentages from a .csv file and parse that data, then call the chart API as per the example.

Comment: tks andrew, I was looking for a working example or the next best thing. But tks for that I will have a further look.